# What are all the types of conformal mappings in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

For instance, in my textbook Complex Analysis by T Gamelin, the conformal mapping from the upper half plane to the unit disk is $z-i\over z+i$ and the converse is $i(1+z)\over (1-z)$. Also it says that the conformal map $w = e^{i\alpha}$ rotates a sector through the angle $\alpha$ and that $w = z^\alpha$ multiplies the angle of a sector by the factor $\alpha$. Is there any sort of compilation anywhere of all the different possible general conformal mapping equations like this, or at least the most relevant ones? I'm trying to organize them but my textbook isn't very good and it's hard for me to learn without organization. Thank you!

Comment: nevermind, after a lot of searching I found a link with a list of them right [here](http://cims.nyu.edu/~holmes/teaching/fall07/complex_handout3.pdf) so hope other people find it useful!